# With cookie regulations (GDPR) in Europe and Google's phase out of 3rd party cookies, do analysis tools like Mixpanel etc. still work?

Tags: web-development, google, cookies, chrome

With the cookie regulations (GDPR) in Europe and Google's phase out of 3rd party cookies, do analysis tools like Mixpanel, Google Analytics, Heap etc. still work properly and continue to provide **reliable** information?

I understand that Google now uses 1st party cookies, and they can do this as they own browser, search engine, and their analytics tool. But how do other analytic tools do this without 3rd party cookies?

And if a number of users in Europe do not consent with using analytic cookies, does the whole analysis **not become very unreliable**?

Comment: I dunno what its like in the land of the free, but GDPR just means you get a big "Accept Cookies! Yes/Fill in a form and don't see the content popup on every website

Comment: Yes, and if a user does not accept those cookies, does it render the web site statistics invalid? If a single user does not accept, certainly not. But if a higher percentage of European users disables 3rd party cookies, does this group not mean this underrepresented in the statistics?